# Regular expression for validating a url

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm a beginner in regexes. My requirement is to validate simple urls to urls with query strings, square brackets etc.. say for eg,

www.test.com?waa=[sample data]

the regex that I wrote only work for simple urls. It fails for the one with square brackets. Any idea?

Comment: posting the regex you wrote might have helped others in helping you; furthermore the web is full of examples, maybe a little research can just do

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need to use regex ?

```
bool isUri = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("http://...", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

Comment: Perfect answer for what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest taking a better look at the following site

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Without actually seeing the Regex you're using I can't provide much insight.  And giving you the answer wouldn't really teach you much either.  Give a man a regex and you help him for a bit.  Teach him regex and he's good for life

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following:

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm

Answer (score 1):

thanks a lot fr reply..
this is what i wrote  ..works for query strings too...but it fails while adding []..

/^(https?|ftp)://(?#)(([a-z0-9$*.+!*\'(),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+(?#)(:([a-z0-9$*.+!*\'(),;\?&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)?(?#)@)?(#)((([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9].)*(#)[a-z]{2}[a-z0-9-]*a-z0-9|(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5].){3}(?#)(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?#))(:\d+)?(?#))(((/+([a-z0-9$_.+!*\'(),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)*(?# )(\?([a-z0-9$_.+!*\'(),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)(?#)?)?)?(?#)(#([a-z0-9$_.+!*\'(),;:@&=-]|%[0-9a-f]{2})*)?(?#)$/i

Comment: My eyes! The goggles do nothing!

Comment: net.tcp://... is also a Uri, not covered by your Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if u want url with http

http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?

if oyu dnt want http in URL then  go for

?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?